# Macro to suppress name in citation if already mentioned in sentence

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am trying to reduce the number of citation commands I use throughout my documents. Ideally I would like to use only one: `\autocites`.

There is any ready to use macro that will suppress the author name from citation produced with `\autocite` or `\autocites` if the same name is already mentioned in the sentence preceding the citation? (Something which is accepted in the APA style)

Please have a look at the MWE for few examples

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @book{abraham,
    address = {New {York}, {NY}},
    title = {Computational social networks: {Tools}, perspectives and applications},
    shorttitle = {Computational social networks},
    publisher = {Springer},
    author = {Abraham, Ajith},
    year = {2012}
  }
  @book{minsky,
    address = {New {York}, {NY}},
    title = {The emotion machine: {Commonsense} thinking, artificial intelligence, and the future of the human mind},
    shorttitle = {The emotion machine},
    publisher = {Simon \& {Schuster}},
    author = {Minsky, Marvin Lee},
    year = {2006}
  }
  @article{lyall,
    title = {Explaining {Support} for {Combatants} during {Wartime}: {A} {Survey} {Experiment} in {Afghanistan}},
    volume = {107},
    number = {04},
    journal = {American {Political} {Science} {Review}},
    author = {Lyall, Jason and Blair, Graeme and Imai, Kosuke},
    month = nov,
    year = {2013},
    pages = {679--705}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
style=apa,
backend=biber,
isbn=false,
url=false,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
backref=false,
firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Abraham wrote \autocite{abraham} but not \autocites{lyall, minsky}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Suppress name in first citation to get as result \textbf{(\citeyear{abraham})}
  \end{itemize}

\item Ajith Abraham wrote \autocite{abraham} but not \autocites{lyall, minsky}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Suppress name in first citation to get as result \textbf{(\citeyear{abraham})}
  \end{itemize}

\item Ajith Abraham wrote \autocites{abraham}[see also][]{minsky, abraham} but not \autocites{lyall, minsky}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Suppress name in first citation to get as result \textbf{(\citeyear{abraham}; see also \cites{minsky, abraham})}
  \end{itemize}

\item Kosuke wrote \autocite{lyall} but not \autocites{minsky, abraham}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Do not suppress name in first citation, although Kosuke is among authors
  \end{itemize}

\item Lyall wrote \autocite{lyall} but not \autocites{minsky, abraham}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Do not suppress name in first citation, although Lyall is among authors
  \end{itemize}

\item Lyall et al. wrote \autocite{lyall} but not \autocites{minsky, abraham}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Suppress name in first citation
  \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the logic of the last 2 examples meant to be? In any case, I don't see how this is meant to work. If you suppress the author, you'll get things like 'Lyall wrote (1990a)' which hardly fits into the flow of text. I'd use something like `\Citeauthor{lyall} wrote \citetitle{lyall} \autocite*{lyall}.` Which obviously involves more citation commands than you want...

Answer (score 2):

The idea is quite nice and the benefit would be enormous in my opinion. But, you can not realize this in (La)TeX for the simple reason that a sentence isn't a logically marked entity. (Within another programming environment that can handle regular expressions it is surely possible, I'd say.) I am very sorry for that somewhat disappointing and short answer.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't mark the first occurence of the name as being the same person it's going to be hard to decide if it is indeed the same person or another by the same name, or not even a name at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're not using the package `apacite`? I don't know of any package or macro or option for APA citing that is as sophisticated as what you're looking for, but writing `\citeyear{foo}` is hardly more work than writing `\cite{foo}` [and `\citeyear{foo}` is what you would need if the author's name was already written in the body of the sentence and you just needed the rest of the citation.]. It has a lot of options that you might be able to adapt for your particular needs here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.